# What the purpose of function-like initialization for builtin types in go?

Tags: go

I know, go converts right side untyped constant to left side typed variable right after `:=` initialization in expression: `a := 5`.
And it looks like the same as `b := int(5)` statement. So, what is the purpose of the second statement and how it differs from the first one?
Also, somewhere, I have seen `[]int(nil)` expression, that's a bit confuse me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally you don't need to use `:=` in combination with a type conversion because it defeats the point of `:=`. `:=` is there to infer the type. The type can generally be inferred from a constant value.

But not always. For example...

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    a := 5
    b := uint(5)
    var c uint = 5

    fmt.Printf("%T\n", a)
    fmt.Printf("%T\n", b)
    fmt.Printf("%T\n", c)
}
```

`a := 5` infers that `a` is of type `int`, but what if you wanted it to be something else? `5` could be [a bunch of different integer types](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Numeric_types). Maybe an unsigned integer? Maybe an integer of a specific length like `int16`?

You can do this by either specifying the type of the constant explicitly, as in `b := uint(8)`, or by specifying the type of the variable explicitly, as in `var c uint = 8`. With `b := uint(8)`, `b`'s type is inferred from the uint constant being assigned to it. With `var c uint = 8`, `8` is inferred to be an unsigned integer because it is being assigned to a variable with the type `uint`. In both cases, `b` and `c` will be of type `uint`.

I'm not aware of any significant difference between `b := uint(8)` and `var b uint = 8`, so which you use is largely up to taste. I have a *slight* preference for `var b uint = 8` because it is visually distinct from `b := 8` to make it clear explicit types are being used.

Answer (score 2):

You are referring to a [type conversion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions).  A type conversion is used to convert a value of one type to a value of another type.

The expression `int(5)` converts the untyped 5 to an `int` with value 5.

The expression `[]int(nil)` converts the untyped `nil` to a `[]int` with value `nil`.

The statements

```
a := 5
b := int(5)
```

declare a `int` variable with value 5. The declaration of `a` uses the [default type](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Constants) for integer constants (which is `int`).  The declaration of `b` explicitly uses the `int` type. Otherwise, they are the same. The use of the default type in the declaration of `a` is usually preferred over the explicit type in the declaration of `b`.  The type conversion is commonly used for types other than the default type. Example `c := int64(22)`.